# Is there a way to speed up python pulp model declaration?

Tags: python, pulp

I am currently working on a linear program using the PuLP library in python and the CPLEX solver. I ran the program on different instances of my problem, and I noticed that the solving part (`model.solve()` line) only took a small part of the execution time of the full function.

I assume the rest of the execution time comes for the declaration of the problem (defining variables, objective function and declaring constraints).

So my question is : is there a generic way to speed up this part ? I assume the most time consuming part is the declaration of constraints, as it's contains a lot of `for` loops, but I don't have a clue how to change this.

Comment: It would be very odd if the model construction time were a factor at all.  You don't say how you profiled this and deduced that the solving was "the quick part"... ?  What kind of overall times are you dealing with here?  What is the total execution time and what is the wall clock or system time reported by the solver for starters...

Comment: Actually for the biggest instance that I tested the solver ran in 43 seconds and the total function (model declaration + solving) took around 30 minutes

Comment: Ok.  Something is very wrong there.  The model construction should run almost instantaneously.  It isn't possible to help much unless you post the code for that--or at least the part of that which is slow.  Are you doing something complicated with your data pre-processing?  Some bizarre pandas operations or some multi-nested loop with data access?  If you can't post your code, you can profile it to see where it is slow with a profiler or just by putting in timestamps or logging.

Comment: I just define the model, objective, variables, and then add the constraints one by one, as I learnt how to use pulp. I actually can't provide much of the code or even of the model, that's why I asked for generic tips (which seem to exist because someone provided an answer to my question)

Answer (score 1):

You can get some ideas at [Writing efficient DOcplex code](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/efficient.ipynb) even if the tricks are for another cplex python api

For instance you may read:

> Common pitfall : Pitfall #1 : use Model.sum(), not Python sum()

You may try to apply those tricks or move to docplex which could be more efficient

Comment: Thank you it seems very useful ! I already was aware of the python sum issue, but I'll check the rest in details. The only problem I would have with using DOcplex is that I won't use the CPLEX solver for my final application, bu rather free solvers as CBC or GLPK.